# Serializer always not valid - ApiView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Why I always have "This field is required" error and `print serializer.data` is empty?

EDIT: only if I use "HTML form" - in "Raw data" it works fine.

serializers.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    email_to = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
```

views.py

```
class TaskAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(**{'data': request.data})
        serializer.is_valid()
        print serializer.data
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: which version of DRF are you on?

Comment: Django version==1.8.12

Comment: @awwester also if I use "Html form" I have: "detail": `"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."`. With raw data it works fine: {"task_id": 5}

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this, but it works fine for me with your exact code - I see `request.data` in the print statement.

I've always done `SerializerClass(data=request.data)`, which is also how they do it in [the source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L19). Maybe try `self.serializer_class(data=request.data)` and see if that makes any difference. Other than that I don't have any other ideas given the current code.

Comment: The same with `self.serializer_class(data=request.data)`. Can you show me your DRF settings from settings.py?

Comment: just default settings for 1.8.3 and added `'rest_framework',
    'api',` into `INSTALLED_APPS` api is just the app i created. I am using python 3 though, might be making a difference

Comment: you get this error sending the request through the built-in browsable api right?